# MDX Calculated measure is not filtered by rows

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a behavior of a calculated measure that I can not understand.
I have a fact table of invoice lines, linked to a dimension table of products.
I have products of different types: R,H,I & N
My aggregate measure is the amount.
My calculated measure AmountR is the amount of products of type R.
When I want to display the amount of the measure AmoutR for a single product "2308" of Type R, I have the total amount of all products of type R displayed.
For me, the calculated measure AmountR should be filtered by the row and only display the amount of the product "2308".

[Cube Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aWqi.png)

First MDX Query :

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[AmountR] AS 
    (
      [Product].[ProductType].&[R]
     ,[Measures].[Amount]
    ) 
   ,FORMAT_STRING = "# ##0.00" 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[AmountR]
   ,[Measures].[Amount]
  } ON 0
 ,[Product].[ProductType].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM Test;
```

==>
[Result is OK]

[image]

Second MDX query filtered on Product 2308 :

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[AmountR] AS 
    (
      [Product].[ProductType].&[R]
     ,[Measures].[Amount]
    ) 
   ,FORMAT_STRING = "# ##0.00" 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[AmountR]
   ,[Measures].[Amount]
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Product].[Product].&[2308] * [Product].[ProductType].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM Test;
```

==>
[Result is KO]

[image]

I can't understand why the value of AmountR is not 121.6 €

I'm working on SQL Server 2019 version, SSAS version is 15.0.35.23
Dev is done under VS 2019.

Thanks for your help !

Franck

Answer (score 0):

One slight syntax change - if using the member name no need for the `&` - so better to use this:

`[Product].[ProductType].[R]`

Testing an equivalent query against Microsoft's AdvWks cube:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[AmountR] AS 
    (
      [Product].[Category].[Bikes]
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
    ) 
   ,FORMAT_STRING = "# ##0.00" 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[AmountR]
   ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Product].[Product Categories].[Product].&[311]
    * 
      [Product].[Category].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This doesn't suffer from the issues you are reporting:

[image]

Therefore I think your cube is not formed correctly and is missing relationships.